# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax.... near 'TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1' at line 15

Tags: mysql, syntax

I tried to import tables from a phpMyAdmin 3.5.8.1 to phpMyAdmin 4.1.14.8. I exporded the file as MYSQL40.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `82umK_commentmeta` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `comment_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_key` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),
  KEY `comment_id` (`comment_id`),
  KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`(191))
) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

My SQL said:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1' at line 15

Comment: replace with TYPE  = MYISAM to ENGINE = MYISAM

Comment: Thank you for the quick help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MySQL 4.x documentation says:

> The `ENGINE` and `TYPE` options specify the storage engine for the table. `ENGINE` was added in MySQL
>   4.0.18 (for 4.0) and 4.1.2 (for 4.1). It is the preferred option name as of those versions, and `TYPE` has
>   become deprecated. `TYPE` is supported throughout the 4.x series, but likely will be removed in the future.

By the MySQL 5.0 documentation (circa 2005), the `TYPE=` syntax is not mentioned.

So you're using syntax that was removed from the product over ten years ago.

I have to comment also that [you should not use MyISAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148/myisam-versus-innodb/17706717#17706717).

Comment: Thank you for the quick help, You are awesome

Answer (score 1):

The last line should say

```
) Engine=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```